# why regex for validating URL is not working in MVC view, though it is working fine on online regex tester

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to validate URL field for this I have used `regex`, which is working OK online but in my view (script) it gives `true` result every time. following is my code.

```
 $('.text-attribute.gt_2_').blur(function () {


        var urlRegExp = /^(ftp:\/\/|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@@!-\/]))?$/;

        //var urlRegExp = new RegExp("((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)");
        var url = $(this).val();
        alert(url);
        var result = urlRegExp.test(url);
        alert(result);

        if ($.trim($(this).val()) != "" && urlRegExp.test($(this).val())==false) {
            alertBox("Please provide valid website address.");
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).focus();
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

your regexp has most of groups optional, which gives true almost every time

**Regexp**

`/^(ftp:\/\/|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!-\/]))?$/;`

let's break it up, you have 5 groups

1. `(ftp:\/\/|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?` is optional
2. `(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?` is optional
3. `(\S+)` looking for some non-space
4. `(:[0-9]+)?` is optional
5. `(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!-\/]))?` is optional again

so, to simplify your expression, you are looking for some non-space characters.

Comment: no use  um, can you help me and give simple 'regexp' for validating URL, I want to validate simple URLs like 'www.Google.com' or 'http://www.google.com' or 'https://www.google.com' just these cases.

Comment: your question asked `why` not `how`. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+regex+url+validation should give you some direction

Comment: All the regexp I have found for validating URL have same problem they work online but not in my view, '^(https?:\/\/)?[0-9a-z]+\.[-_0-9a-z]+\.[0-9a-z]+$' @Neverever